# how to update another fields based on drop down selection using php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table where i store item id and its description. now i am displaying them as dropdown menu from mysql. here is table

```
stock_id            description
2013_1Mess_Jan  Canteen
2013_Mess_August    Canteen
2013_Mess_Dec   Canteen
2013_Mess_July  Canteen
2013_Mess_Nov   Canteen
2013_Mess_Oct   Canteen
2013_Mess_Sep   Canteen
A4_Sheets           Stationary
Aloo_Parantha   Canteen
BBA11_4th_sem   Fine
Biscuit_02          Canteen
Biscuit_05          Canteen
Biscuit_10  c      Canteen
Black_White PrintOut
Book_Lost   Library
BP_BBA12_2nd    FIne
BP_PGDM_11  FIne
BP_PGDM_12  FIne
```

now i want if i select stock_id then description will automatically show its discription. here stock is is unique key.
here is my code ( i know it is possible with ajax but i am zero with it)

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 $db = mysql_select_db("ex_smartcard2013",$con);

 $getitem=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 0_stock_master ORDER BY stock_id ASC");
$item = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitem))
{
  $item .= '<option value = "'.$row['stock_id'].'">'.$row['stock_id'].'</option>';
}

$getdescription=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 0_stock_master ");
$description = '';
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdescription))
{
  $description .= '<option value = "'.$row2['description'].'">'.$row2['description'].'</option>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0047)http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Editable Invoice</title>

    <script src="./Editable Invoice_files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Editable Invoice_files/example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

        <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>

        <div id="identity">


</body>
</html>


        <table id="items">

          <tbody><tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Unit Cost</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
          </tr>

          <tr class="item-row">
              <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><select name="age"> <?php echo $item; ?> </select><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
              <td class="description"><select name="age"> <?php echo $description; ?> </select></td>
              <td><textarea class="cost">$0.00</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
              <td><span class="price">$0.00</span></td>
          </tr>



          <tr id="hiderow">
            <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$0.00</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$0.00</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
              <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$0.00</div></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing please try to describe more?

Comment: Nothing i dont know how to do this

Comment: you need to use ajax and php try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861365/updating-drop-down-on-change-of-another-drop-down-using-php-ajax?rq=1

Comment: this is working but i want auto update description field as i select stock_id from drop down

Comment: i tried but its not working description is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use ajax to post url id and get the result from ajax

```
var data = 'id='+yourid; 
$.post(
      'abc.php',
       data 
      success(function(resp){
          jsonData = $.parseJSON(resp);
          alert(jsonData);
      });
```

abc.php

```
id = $_POST['id'];
your query
echo json_encode(array(
description => $description
));
```